# KQL - The mystery of the 6th row

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I am playing around with data visualization. To help make my legend more descriptive in an analytics query, I created a new column, `Result`. This concatenates an error code with some of its description. The problem is, when I create that new column, now, I get 6 `Result` combinations in my output, instead of the expected 5.

My assumption is that since I am defining `top 5 by AvgCount` and am filtering against that, my `project` line should have no effect on the number of results that are output. It does, and I haven't been able to figure out why.

So, as is, the below query will return 6 `Result` types

```
let lastmonth = iff(lastmonthNumber == 0, 12, lastmonthNumber); 
let year = getyear(datetime(now)) - iff(lastmonth == 12, 1, 0); 
let dateBegin = make_datetime(year, lastmonth, 01);
let dateEnd = endofmonth(dateBegin);
let top5ResultTypes = SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated between (dateBegin .. dateEnd)
| where ResultType != 0
| summarize CountPerDay=count() by ResultType, bin(TimeGenerated, 24h)
| summarize AvgCount=avg(CountPerDay) by ResultType
| top 5 by AvgCount
| project ResultType;
SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated between (dateBegin .. dateEnd)
| where ResultType != 0 and ResultType in (top5ResultTypes)
| summarize Count=count() by ResultType, ResultDescription, bin(TimeGenerated, 24h)
| project Count, Result=strcat(ResultType, " : ", substring(ResultDescription, 0, 30)), TimeGenerated
| render timechart
    with (
    title="Top 5 Login Failure Types Per Day",
    xtitle="Date",
    ytitle="Count",
    ysplit=panels 
    )
```

If I leave the `ResultType` column intact and don't extend my new column, I get 5 results, as expected.

```
let lastmonth = iff(lastmonthNumber == 0, 12, lastmonthNumber); 
let year = getyear(datetime(now)) - iff(lastmonth == 12, 1, 0); 
let dateBegin = make_datetime(year, lastmonth, 01);
let dateEnd = endofmonth(dateBegin);
let top5ResultTypes = SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated between (dateBegin .. dateEnd)
| where ResultType != 0
| summarize CountPerDay=count() by ResultType, bin(TimeGenerated, 24h)
| summarize AvgCount=avg(CountPerDay) by ResultType
| top 5 by AvgCount
| project ResultType;
SigninLogs
| where TimeGenerated between (dateBegin .. dateEnd)
| where ResultType in (top5ResultTypes)
| summarize Count=count() by ResultType, bin(TimeGenerated, 24h)
| render timechart
    with (
    title="Top 5 Login Failure Types Per Day",
    xtitle="Date",
    ytitle="Count",
    ysplit=panels 
    )
```

Comment: Is the additional column breaking up the results differently so the `AvgCount` ends up introducing ties? That's the only reason I can think of that top 5 would return 6 rows. I suggest you analyse in tabular format and check the values of `AvgCount`

Comment: @Nick.Mc, maybe? If I extend the column in the top 5 function, then it works as expected. I just don't know why it is behaving this way and so am more looking to understand what's going on here that I just don't get.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my observations:

When I add `, bin(timestamp, 24h)` I get extra 4 rows as below:

[image]

If i do not add that i get 5 rows as below:

[image]

So for me the problem creator was timestamp for you it maybe TimeGenerated. If i add extra column(extended) without timestamp i got 5 records:

[image]

When I add timestamp I get 9 records:

[image]

For me the issue was with Timestamp, So I came into conclusion that Output depends on the time and also new extended columns in kql.

Comment: I also experimented with this in tabular output but still don't really get why the change impacts the search against the filtered top 5 result types. It is not tie-breaking or anything like that - from a query construction perspective, clearly, I am not doing something as efficiently as I should. Just don't know what the doing it correct answer would be.